# JQuery - .map is not a function

Tags: jquery, array.prototype.map

I have the following code:

```
var fieldsJson = formBuilder.actions.getData('json', true);

console.log(fieldsJson);

var nameArr = fieldsJson.map(function (item) { return item.name });
```

But I keep getting error:

```
fieldsJson.map is not a function
```

The console is clearly showing fieldsJson to be an object array as follows:

```
[
  {
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Text Field",
    "className": "form-control",
    "name": "testfield",
    "subtype": "text",
    "customField": true
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Text Field",
    "className": "form-control",
    "name": "testfield",
    "subtype": "text",
    "customField": true
  }
]
```

So why is it throwing error for map function?

Comment: Are you sure it's a map and not a JSON string?  `console.log(typeof fieldsJson)`

Comment: If typeof(fieldsJson) returns 'object' it should be working. Can you reproduce the error in a fiddle?

Comment: What about `fieldsJSON.length`?

Comment: @mikeb You are right, it's a json string. How do I convert it to an object array?

Comment: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: See my answer, I added the line you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fieldsJson is a String, you need to parse it with `JSON.parse`:

```
var fieldsJson = formBuilder.actions.getData('json', true);

console.log(fieldsJson);

fieldsJson = JSON.parse(fieldsJson)
var nameArr = fieldsJson.map(function (item) { return item.name });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost certainly looking at a JSON string representation.  This will also catch any malformed json:

```
try {
  JSON.parse(fieldsJson);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Further info for [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that your `JSON.parse(fieldsJson)` is useless in this context, since it does not modify the fieldsJson variable and does not assign the value...